# Seq2Seq in Tensorflow, but I get ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru_cell_3 is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on understanding how to use RNNs in Tensorflow for Seq2Seq models, and I get to the last step of doing a dynamic RNN and I get a dynamic dynamic_decode step and I get the error:

"ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru_cell_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]"

```
import tensorflow as tf

data_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,102,300]) 

batch_lengths = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_max(tf.sign(data_inputs),2),1),tf.int32)

encoder_cell_forward = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units = 150)

encoder_cell_backward = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units = 150)

_ , state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
    encoder_cell_forward,encoder_cell_backward,
    data_inputs,sequence_length = batch_lengths,
    dtype = tf.float32 )

state = tf.concat(state,1)

decoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units = 300)

helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(state,batch_lengths)

projection_layer = tf.layers.Dense(
    units = 300,activation= None,trainable =True )

decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
    decoder_cell, helper, state,
    output_layer=projection_layer)

final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
    decoder,maximum_iterations= 102,impute_finished=False)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out , in the line with the training helper:

```
tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(state,batch_lengths)
```

state needs to be the sequence batch you are wanting to decode, if you use the encoded state it throws the error.